# How to use the schannel certificate (context) and private (ncrypt) key with openssl or rustls for actix?

Tags: rust, openssl, actix-web, schannel

I need to get certificate and private key from windows store instead of the current two files.
I have generated a PKCS12 using the two and have imported it into the windows store.

I am using [schannel rs](https://github.com/steffengy/schannel-rs) to find the relevant certificate and:

1. get the certificate context (which can be transformed to PEM or DER format and also parsed to X509 using [x509 parser](https://github.com/rusticata/x509-parser))
2. its relevant `NcryptKey`.

The program is already using [rust openssl](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl)'s `SslAcceptorBuilder` to load from the certificate file and to use the `PKey<Private>` which also loads the private key from file.

Question: How can the `CertContext` context be loaded into the `SslAcceptorBuilder` as certificate and how can I use the `NcryptKey` as `PKey<Private>`? (or also load it into the `SslAcceptorBuilder` which is the required anyway).

As the `SslAcceptor` **can** indeed load an X509, I have searched the Rust openssl documentation for means of creating one `X509Ref` using the `X509Builder` but none of them uses bytes of a certificate already in memory. Or at least I haven't yet found a method. Same stands for the `PKey`.

At the moment I am dumping the certificate as PEM in a file and load the file and delete the file.
It is a level higher than having the file already there, but still. Moreover the private key file is still there. So, no security whatsoever.

Any ideas? Did I miss something? Maybe I cannot avoid using yet another package like [rustls](https://github.com/rustls/rustls) or [rustls-native-certs](https://github.com/rustls/rustls-native-certs)?

UPDATE

After switching from rust openssl to rustls, I am able to use the certificate context as DER format for the `ServerConfig` builder. But I am still missing the part of the Ncrypt key to either `PrivateKeyDer` or something other usable. Going over schannel-rs repository now, to see if I find some answers there.

Answer (score 0):

Solved everything using the [rustls-cng](https://github.com/rustls/rustls-cng) in combination with [rustls](https://github.com/rustls/rustls).

The [server example](https://github.com/rustls/rustls-cng/blob/dev/examples/server.rs) provides enough to use a certificate from the windows store and its password to pass on to the `HttpServer` of `Actix-web` using `.bind_rustls_0_22()`. For some reason, you do not even have to have administrative rights for `Local Machine` stored certificates. It also provides the possibility importing one from a `pfx/p12` file which stores together the certificate and private key. It worked like a charm.